# Save switch position after closing app

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, uiswitch

I wanted to know how to save the position of a switch to close and open the application ?

```
-(IBAction)switch_poids_passagers:(UISwitch *)sender {

 NSString *poids_passagers_total;
 if(sender.on) {
      poids_passagers_total = @"1";

 } else {
      poids_passagers_total = @"2";

 }

 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:poids_passagers_total forKey:@"poids_passagers_total"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

}

Comment: what is the issue you are having ?

Comment: I have a switch in a view, i switch ON this one, and i would to close the application. When I open it, the switch is in "OFF" position. Why ?

Comment: you should set the switch back to on state based on the NSUserdefaults value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` can save and retrieve `BOOLS` with a pair methods it provides:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setBool:self.myUISwitch.on forKey:@"switchValue"];
// ...
```

Later on, maybe in viewWillAppear...

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL switchValue = [defaults boolForKey:@"switchValue"];
self.myUISwitch.on = switchValue;
```